# Origin of tokens in Google trends API call

Tags: http, get, google-api

When I download a CSV from a Google trends query (e.g. [here](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=trump)), I see a HTTP GET request to

```
https://www.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv
```

with params

```
req:{"time":"2012-02-18 2017-02-18","resolution":"WEEK","locale":"en-GB","comparisonItem":[{"geo":{},"complexKeywordsRestriction":{"keyword":[{"type":"BROAD","value":"trump"}]}}],"requestOptions":{"property":"","backend":"IZG","category":0}}
token:APP6_UEAAAAAWKm9N57FxjXrnfxhxhe5SEax6DyR97sY
tz:-120
```

The req and tz params make sense, but I am unsure how the token is generated. Can someone explain to me where this comes from? Do I need to use oauth2 packages to create these tokens?

Answer (score 7):

This token is generated for result widgets, each widget will have its own token.

**Where is this token come from?**

When page https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=trump is opened, an Ajax `GET` request is sent to https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore, with query parameters:
[image]

In the response of this Ajax request, there is a `widgets` field which contains all result widget data. Each widget will have a unique token:[image]

When *Download CSV* operation is triggered (on specific widget, `GET` request to https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv), the `token` information of that widget is extracted and delivered as query parameter:[image]

Please note the token in the response and the token in the download csv request is identical (for the same widget).

**How is the token generated?**

Theoretically, all random and unique string can be used as token to protect widget. Google may have its own algorithm.