# How to get the *widget-token* for downloading csv-files from Google Trends?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-get, google-trends

Im currently trying to retrieve data from the google trends site directly into python. By inspecting the "download csv"-button I was able to extract the underlying url of the file, which looks like this:

https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv?req=%7B%22time%22%3A%222018-08-30%202019-08-30%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%22WEEK%22%2C%22locale%22%3A%22de%22%2C%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22geo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22complexKeywordsRestriction%22%3A%7B%22keyword%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22BROAD%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22trump%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22requestOptions%22%3A%7B%22property%22%3A%22%22%2C%22backend%22%3A%22IZG%22%2C%22category%22%3A0%7D%7D&token=APP6_UEAAAAAXWrEbGVLW-ssfeQvOJgr9938DRgYO1sm&tz=-120

Unquoted :

`https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv?req={"time":"2018-08-30 2019-08-30","resolution":"WEEK","locale":"de","comparisonItem":[{"geo":{},"complexKeywordsRestriction":{"keyword":[{"type":"BROAD","value":"trump"}]}}],"requestOptions":{"property":"","backend":"IZG","category":0}}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAXWrEbGVLW-ssfeQvOJgr9938DRgYO1sm&tz=-120`

I can now easily get this csv into a pandas dataframe. Ideally, I would now just manipulate the url in order to make custom requests and load new data. The problem I have is that I cannot use the same `token` parameter, since it is somehow generated newly for each individual csv-request. I think that the answer from shaochuancs in [Origin of tokens in Google trends API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317489/origin-of-tokens-in-google-trends-api-call) describes the problem as I am facing it. Can anyone explain how I can request this token which I could then use for the second request ( the actual csv download )? :/

Comment: What is the start url you used in order to view the download csv button that then lead to the above url generation when pressed?

Comment: @QHarr First I go to https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=trump and then then I have to press the download button, which then generates the request

Comment: @QHarr help pls :((